# Why one process is taking so many resources

Tags: mysql, process, top

My website is being very slow or non-responsive. A quick look at the `top` command shows me something like this:

```
PID  USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR  S %CPU  %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1709 mysql     20   0  828m  432m 5584 S 382.6  5.4   7414:24 mysqld
```

The rest of the processes are way below those values. Obviously MySQL is having some issues. How can I check what is actually going on and why does it take so many resources?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `show processlist` in the mysql console to get a list of the currently-running queries.  Look for ones which have been running for a while, to see what they're doing.  Chances are there's a few queries doing monster amounts of work (usually due to poor indexes).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [womble's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/88258/why-one-proccess-is-taking-so-many-resources/88259#88259) (which point to optimizing your queries); for those that find 382.6% CPU usage puzzling, note that MySQL is a multithreaded server.  It probably was running 4 threads full-tilt, almost monopolizing 4 cores (i'm sure it can do even more in a big enough machine).  Pressing 'H' on `top` shows each thread separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should also have a look at the slow log of mysql, if it is enabled.

Comment: Yes I did check that and found out that the file is over 200MB of never seen data. I have a lot of optimizing to do now.